# Bigquery API for get the job information

Tags: google-bigquery, google-apis-explorer

support team,

I am using google bigquery API python lib to test some operations. One purpose is to get the job information. Then we can better control all our queries from the API. I found there is a get() method mentioned in the REST reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get), which can get the job information. But in the API python lib [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/translate-client.html), I can not find any doc about this get() method or something can finish the same operation.

Can you help to provide me any guide doc about any method in the python lib can get the job information?

Thanks
Zhihong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Elliott's suggestion, I got the job info I need after run a query, but not figure out how to fetch the job info for an exist job, which I think not needed anymore if got query info after each operation. The python code is as below:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
query = client.run_sunc_query(sql)
query.use_legacy_sql = False
query.use_query_cache = True
query.run()
trows = query.total_rows
billed_byte = query.total_bytes_processed
```

More query info parameters can be found [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-query.html) and more example code can be found [here](http://gcloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery-usage.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the documentation for the translate API rather than BigQuery. See `job_from_resource` under the [BigQuery client documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.job_from_resource).

Comment: Hi, @Elliott, thanks for the reply. Actually I tried job_from_resource(), but can not make it work. Do you know where I can find an example for the "parameter"? I found some clue in the BQ test here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/tests/unit/test_client.py, but did not figure it out.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you are trying to look up. Generally you would pass the result of another client operation, such as `run_async_query`, to it.

Comment: Hi, @Elliott, sorry for any confusing. I am trying to get the job information as the get() method describ in the REST reference. You mentioned about "the result for the another client operation", do you mean like jobId from another client operation? Yes, I know a projectId and jobId is needed. But I do not know how to pass this info to the parameter for job_from_resource()

Comment: Hi,@Elliott, I think I get what you mean. My question above is want to know how to construct the parameter by my own based on existing jobId.  I will see how to get the resource dict, which is the parameter for the job_from_resource() from another client operation.

Comment: Hi, @Elliott, using your suggestion, it works. And I get the job info I need after a client operation.